# Не отрабатывает ErrorDocument

Tags: apache, apache2, jboss

Не могу настроить обработку ErrorDocument 503 на балансировщике Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS), который смотрит на JBoss AS7.
Вот конфиг:

```
#NameVirtualHost test.ru:443
<VirtualHost test.ru:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes Includes
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 503 "/error.html"
    ServerName test.ru
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    <Proxy balancer://ajp-cluster>
    BalancerMember ajp://10.100.10.10:8009 route=node1 KeepAlive=On retry=0 timeout=60 ttl=60
#   BalancerMember ajp://192.168.1.2:8009 route=node2
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
        ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
    ProxyErrorOverride On
    ProxyPass balancer://ajp-cluster/
    </Location>    
    ProxyRequests off

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/test.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/test.key
</VirtualHost>
```

При открытии страницы, возвращается ошибка:

> Service Unavailable
>       The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>       Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Если вместо пути к файлу с ошибкой, указать текст ошибки, то отрабатывает корректно.

```
ErrorDocument 503 text error
```

Как правильно обработать ErrorDocument 503?